# Does a free tool/toolset to do CI/CD for Talend Open Studio 7.x exist?

Tags: talend

I am looking for a tool, or set of tools, to do CI/CD with Talend Open Studio 7.x.

The Talend Open Studio instance is 'on prem' (i.e., we are not using Talend Cloud) and we do not use TAC (the Talend Admin Center).

I am not looking for an opinion of "the best tool/toolset".  I am just asking the community if such a tool/toolset even exists.

To the best of my knowledge, to do CI/CD with Talend Open Studio 7.x the user is kind of stuck with using tools provided by Talend and those tools are not free or cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI/CD can be done only for License version of Talend. The license version of Talend includes a console application which connects to TAC to create builds in automated fashion.

No such ready made tools are present in Open source version of Talend for CI/CD.

Comment: So I’m guessing, unless you want to “roll your own”, you’ll have to purchased a licensed tool(s) — like TAC — from Talend.

Comment: @tale852150 there's also cloud licenses that give you access to studio + CI

Comment: @BalazsGunics Good feedback. I’ve been looking at the Talend cloud as an option but I haven’t had a chance to do any pricing. Do you happen to know if it is, generally speaking, cheaper than on prem TAC?

Comment: @BalazsGunics Apparently one can do some CI by using Talend Open Studio from the CLI.

Comment: @BalazsGunics I suspect I will have to go the CLI route in order to do CI. I’ll have to roll my own with another tool to do deployment.  I also plan on looking at Jenkins as a possible option and see where that might fit in. Do me a favor and upvote the OP and I will except any answer you give that includes your comments that you have already provided.